# Transfer closed with xxxx bytes remaining to read

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

When I try to query parse server and the data is  big this exception accrue How to handle that

```
Type: Parse\ParseException
Code: 18
Message: transfer closed with 985517 bytes remaining to read
File: /home/ramy/php_api/ERP-PHP/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php
Line: 505
```